# How to add XAML Resources to App.XAML for an ArcGIS Pro SDK Add-In?

Tags: c#, wpf, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am in the process of creating a .NET add-in for ArcGIS Pro SDK.

I have working code in a WPF application that I want to include in my add-in.

The issue is that there is no there is no `App.xaml` for an ArcGIS Pro add-in file to define my application level resources. ex: (shortened for visibility):
`<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> <ResourceDictionary Source="pack:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;" /> </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>`

I've read [this](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/) but it seemed more complex than necessary for my needs.

How can I add application resources to the ArcGIS Pro Plugin without the presence of the `App.xaml`?

Comment: Open or Create App.xaml file in your project. If it doesn't exist, create Application.Resources element, 
<Application.Resources>
 </Application.Resources> and place resources inside it.
See example: https://developers.arcgis.com/net/10-2/desktop/guide/use-the-mvvm-design-pattern.htm